# Не работает autocomplete="off"

Tags: html, css

Всем привет. Есть три поля:

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off" placeholder="E-mail" required>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="phone" name="phone" autocomplete="off" required>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off" placeholder="ФИО" required>
```

Но браузер, при фокусе на каком-то из поля, подставляет автозаполнение. Как его отключить? Почему не работает?

Comment: В Хроме проблема не наблюдается - подсказки не вылазят ни в одном из полей

Comment: https://ideahunter.kz/cabinet/registration вот тут работает(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо добавить `autocomplete="off"` для тега `form`.